# FFmpeg hevc_nvenc encoder B Frame problem

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, transcoding, hevc, nvenc

I'm using the latest FFmpeg windows Build (2022-12-02 12:44) from [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases).
I'm trying to encode a video into HEVC codec using hevc_nvenc encoder. But it says `[hevc_nvenc @ 00000263983f4280] B frames as references are not supported`. Cause my GPU GTX1060 (GP106) doesn't support hardware accelerate encode HEVC of B frames.
[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV8B4.png)

I tried to disable the B frames by adding the parameter `-bf 0`, but it doesn't work.
Then I tried to use the latest build from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and it is the same. But when I tried to use an older build (2021-02-28 12:32) of BtbN, it doesn't have the problem.
Is there a workaround to bypass this B frame problem? Cause I don't want to switch to an older build. Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/issues/78

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Gyan. The [solution](https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/issues/78) is to add parameter `-b_ref_mode 0`